# Flutter Error: type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<Obejct>' in type cast - when trying to use a GIF as background

Tags: flutter

My goal is to use a GIF as the background.

I tried this:

```
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          image: true? Image.asset(
            "images/gif_day.mp4",
            height: 125.0,
            width: 125.0,
          ) as ImageProvider : 
           const AssetImage('assets/images/Environment.png'),
        ),  
      ),
)
```

But I get the error:
`type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<Obejct>' in type cast`

I think this is a known issue and I tried the solutions from other posts with the same problem, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not assign Image to the ImageProvider try this instead

```
 return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: true? AssetImage(
        "images/gif_day.gif",
      )  
       const AssetImage('assets/images/Environment.png'),
    ),  
  ),
)
```

if you want to use gif as image this is the [website](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif) convert your video to gif here and use it as AssetImage widget